# .NET Session variable is null - for all users

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, session, iis

**Problem description**

I have an ASP.NET app in which the users have different rights, and are logged in through Facebook. The app includes (among other things) filling out some forms. Some users have access to forms others don't. The forms can sometimes require some searching in books and/or on the internet before being able to submit them.

As such, we're having problems with session time-outs (it seemed), where users would be met with "Not authorized to see this page/form" after doing research somewhere else.

**Attempted solutions**

I've created a log function that logs the state of a handful of variables on strategic points in the application. I've pinpointed the problem to the fact that the Session variable "UserRole" is null when the problem occurs.

*Relogging*

The obvious solution is: "Have you tried relogging?" - which *should* reset the session and allow the user back to the form they want. On logout, I use

```
Session.Clear();
Session.RemoveAll();
```

and I create a new session with relevant variables (including UserRole) on login. This doesn't help, though.

*Keeping session alive*

One way to do it is just increase the standard 20-minute Session length to an arbitrary, higher number (say 2 hours). Although that could be viable during beta (there are only around 5 users right now), it is not a viable solution in the long haul as the server would have to keep the Session objects from many users for longer time, exponentially increasing server demands.

Instead, I created a 'dummy' .ashx handler "RefreshSession.ashx", that can recieve a POST request and return "200" statuscode. I then created a jQuery function in the shared part of the app (that all the pages use) that calls this handler every 10 minutes in order to refresh the session as long as the tab is open in the browser. I've checked the network traffic, and it works as intended, calling the handler even if the window is minimized or the user is viewing another tab. This did not solve the problem either.

**A caveat**

When one of the users encounter the problem, they call me or my programming partner up. Of course, we go and see if we get the same issue. We all have the same (admin) rights. The 'funny' thing is that we see the exact same error on the same subpage - even if we haven't had any contact with the application for days.

The problem will 'fix itself' (i.e. let users with proper role back on the subpage) after a while, but not even republishing the app to the server will reset it manually.

Therefore, it seems to not be a simpel session error as supposed from the "UserRole" session variable being null after 15-20 minutes of inactivity. It seems to be saved somewhere internally in the server state.

My problem is, that I now have no idea where to look and how to progress. I was hoping that someone here might have an idea for a solution, or at least be able to point me in the right direction? :-)

Thank you all for your time, it is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your session time out? How are you setting the session variables? If the user doesn't sit idle for a period of time can that user access the page(s) in question?

Comment: I haven't specifically set a session timeout anywhere, but have read that the standard .NET timeout is 20 minutes unless changed. Session variables are set like this:  `Session["UserRole"] = uncheckedUser.UserRole.UserRoleId;`  . If the user just fills out forms normally without being idle, everything works fine

Comment: I would suggest giving the user a notification that the session is about to expire, this is completely normal behavior for session variables.  When the session ends, the variable is disposed.  If you are expecting large idle times, I would suggest not using session variables or setting the session to a longer amount of time.

Comment: If only it affected one user at a time, that would be an allright. It's a huge problem, however, that noone can use the app when one user's session expires.

Comment: Are you using multiple worker processes? I have experienced this same type of problem when I had multiple worker processes turned on. What happens is that the worker processes cross the sessions between users.  We found this because we could see what user the application was running under, and all users would eventually sync up to all being one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on MaCron's comment to the question, we decided to keep the information in the user's cookies instead of the session variables. Everything seemed to point to us having exactly that issue, and deadlines being deadlines and with me not being able to figure out how to disable the synchronization of worker processes, this seemed to be a feasible and comparatively easy fix.